# Setup sonarQube with PMD CPD for scala project

Tags: scala, sonarqube, pmd, sonarqube-scan, cpd

Trying to setup scala project with SonarQueue 5.6.6 for code duplication via PMD CPD through SBT. I did manage to run CPD via SBT to generate cpd.xml but just wandering how to propagate that info to Sonar. Anybody has any insight how it works?
When running sonar-scanner I see following lines:

```
00:22:18.577 INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (wrapped)
00:22:18.577 INFO: DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for scala
00:22:18.577 DEBUG: No CpdMapping for language scala
00:22:18.577 INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (wrapped) (done) | time=0ms
00:22:18.578 INFO: Calculating CPD for 0 files
00:22:18.579 INFO: CPD calculation finished
```

Any help greatly appriciated